# parallelized algorithm for evaluating a 1-d array of functions on a same-length 1d numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, scientific-computing

The upshot of the below is that I have an embarrassingly parallel for loop that I am trying to thread. There's a bit of rigamarole to explain the problem, but despite all the verbosity, I **think** this should be a rather trivial problem that the multiprocessing module is designed to solve easily.

I have a large length-N array of k distinct functions, and a length-N array of abcissa. Thanks to the clever solution provided by @senderle described in [Efficient algorithm for evaluating a 1-d array of functions on a same-length 1d numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459896/efficient-algorithm-for-evaluating-a-1-d-array-of-functions-on-a-same-length-1d), I have a fast numpy-based algorithm that I can use to evaluate the functions at the abcissa to return a length-N array of ordinates:

```
def apply_indexed_fast(abcissa, func_indices, func_table):
    """ Returns the output of an array of functions evaluated at a set of input points 
    if the indices of the table storing the required functions are known. 

    Parameters 
    ----------
    func_table : array_like 
        Length k array of function objects

    abcissa : array_like 
        Length Npts array of points at which to evaluate the functions. 

    func_indices : array_like 
        Length Npts array providing the indices to use to choose which function 
        operates on each abcissa element. Thus func_indices is an array of integers 
        ranging between 0 and k-1. 

    Returns 
    -------
    out : array_like 
        Length Npts array giving the evaluation of the appropriate function on each 
        abcissa element. 
    """
    func_argsort = func_indices.argsort()
    func_ranges = list(np.searchsorted(func_indices[func_argsort], range(len(func_table))))
    func_ranges.append(None)
    out = np.zeros_like(abcissa)

    for i in range(len(func_table)):
        f = func_table[i]
        start = func_ranges[i]
        end = func_ranges[i+1]
        ix = func_argsort[start:end]
        out[ix] = f(abcissa[ix])

    return out
```

What I'm now trying to do is use multiprocessing to parallelize the for loop inside this function. Before describing my approach, for clarity I'll briefly sketch how the algorithm @senderle developed works. If you can read the above code and understand it immediately, just skip the next paragraph of text.

First we find the array of indices that sorts the input *func_indices*, which we use to define the length-k *func_ranges* array of integers. The integer entries of *func_ranges* control the function that gets applied to the appropriate sub-array of the input *abcissa*, which works as follows. Let *f* be the i^th function in the input *func_table*. Then the slice of the input *abcissa* to which we should apply the function *f* is *slice(func_ranges[i], func_ranges[i+1])*. So once *func_ranges* is calculated, we can just run a simple for loop over the input *func_table* and successively apply each function object to the appropriate slice, filling our output array. See the code below for a minimal example of this algorithm in action.

```
def trivial_functional(i): 
    def f(x):
        return i*x
    return f

k = 250
func_table = np.array([trivial_functional(j) for j in range(k)])

Npts = 1e6
abcissa = np.random.random(Npts)
func_indices = np.random.random_integers(0,len(func_table)-1,Npts)

result = apply_indexed_fast(abcissa, func_indices, func_table)
```

So my goal now is to use multiprocessing to parallelize this calculation. I thought this would be straightforward using my usual trick for threading embarrassingly parallel for loops. But my attempt below raises an exception that I do not understand.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
def apply_indexed_parallelized(abcissa, func_indices, func_table):
    func_argsort = func_indices.argsort()
    func_ranges = list(np.searchsorted(func_indices[func_argsort], range(len(func_table))))
    func_ranges.append(None)
    out = np.zeros_like(abcissa)

    num_cores = cpu_count()
    pool = Pool(num_cores)

    def apply_funci(i):
        f = func_table[i]
        start = func_ranges[i]
        end = func_ranges[i+1]
        ix = func_argsort[start:end]
        out[ix] = f(abcissa[ix])

    pool.map(apply_funci, range(len(func_table)))
    pool.close()

    return out

result = apply_indexed_parallelized(abcissa, func_indices, func_table)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I have seen this elsewhere on SO: [Multiprocessing: How to use Pool.map on a function defined in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-using-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class). One by one, I have tried each method proposed there; in all cases, I get a "too many files open" error because the threads were never closed, or the adapted algorithm simply hangs. This seems like there should be a simple solution since this is nothing more than threading an embarrassingly parallel for loop.

Comment: If I recall correctly, your problem is due to using a function that's not accessible from the `__main__` namespace (i.e. passing in a function to pool that's defined inside another function or otherwise out of the main scope).

Comment: Yes, I've come across this suggestion before, but I haven't seen anyone implement a solution. My first thought is that this is an extremely restrictive condition that python is enforcing. Can you see how to adapt this problem to conform to this requirement? I don't see how to do it, since func_table and func_indices are necessarily bound within the namespace of my function.

Comment: One solution is to pass in a instance of a class instead.  However you have a deeper problem. You're treating the numpy arrays as though they're shared memory.  Instead, a copy will be made and passed to each process independently.  The original array won't be modified.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that is a deeper problem. This is the first time I've tried to parallelize something in this fashion before, so I hadn't encountered this before. Do you know how to use the multiprocessing module in a way that permits the threads to have shared access to numpy arrays? Or can you point me to a resource where I can read about this?

Comment: Other questions about numpy and multiporocessing reference `sharedmem`, https://github.com/sturlamolden/sharedmem-numpy.  But it just saves memory, not time.

Comment: If the functions release the GIL (most Numpy functions do, to some degree) you could benefit from actual threading instead of separate processes. For quick testing change the first line to `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool, cpu_count`. This should remove the need to pickle everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Warning/Caveat:

You may not want to apply `multiprocessing` to this problem.  You'll find that relatively simple operations on large arrays, the problems will be memory bound with `numpy`. The bottleneck is moving data from RAM to the CPU caches. The CPU is starved for data, so throwing more CPUs at the problem doesn't help much.  Furthermore, your current approach will pickle and make a copy of the entire array for every item in your input sequence, which adds lots of overhead.

There are plenty of cases where `numpy` + `multiprocessing` is *very* effective, but you need to make sure you're working with a CPU-bound problem. Ideally, it's a CPU-bound problem with relatively small inputs and outputs to alleviate the overhead of pickling the input and output. For many of the problems that `numpy` is most often used for, that's not the case.

---

### Two Problems with Your Current Approach

On to answering your question:

Your immediate error is due to passing in a function that's not accessible from the global scope (i.e. a function defined inside a function).

However, you have another issue.  You're treating the numpy arrays as though they're shared memory that can be modified by each process.  Instead, when using `multiprocessing` the original array will be pickled (effectively making a copy) and passed to each process independently.  The original array will never be modified.

---

### Avoiding the `PicklingError`

As a minimal example to reproduce your error, consider the following:

```
import multiprocessing

def apply_parallel(input_sequence):
    def func(x):
        pass
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(func, input_sequence)
    pool.close()

foo = range(100)
apply_parallel(foo)
```

This will result in:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup 
               __builtin__.function failed
```

Of course, in this simple example, we could simply move the function definition back into the `__main__` namespace. However, in yours, you need it to refer to data that's passed in.   Let's look at an example that's a bit closer to what you're doing:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def parallel_rolling_mean(data, window):
    data = np.pad(data, window, mode='edge')
    ind = np.arange(len(data)) + window

    def func(i):
        return data[i-window:i+window+1].mean()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = pool.map(func, ind)
    pool.close()
    return result

foo = np.random.rand(20).cumsum()
result = parallel_rolling_mean(foo, 10)
```

There are multiple ways you could handle this, but a common approach is something like:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

class RollingMean(object):
    def __init__(self, data, window):
        self.data = np.pad(data, window, mode='edge')
        self.window = window

    def __call__(self, i):
        start = i - self.window
        stop = i + self.window + 1
        return self.data[start:stop].mean()

def parallel_rolling_mean(data, window):
    func = RollingMean(data, window)
    ind = np.arange(len(data)) + window

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = pool.map(func, ind)
    pool.close()
    return result

foo = np.random.rand(20).cumsum()
result = parallel_rolling_mean(foo, 10)
```

Great! It works!

---

However, if you scale this up to large arrays, you'll soon find that it will either run very slow (which you can speed up by increasing `chunksize` in the `pool.map` call) or you'll quickly run out of RAM (once you increase the `chunksize`).

`multiprocessing` pickles the input so that it can be passed to separate and independent python processes.  This means you're making a copy of the *entire* array for *every* `i` you operate on.

We'll come back to this point in a bit...

---

### `multiprocessing` Does not share memory between processes

The `multiprocessing` module works by pickling the inputs and passing them to independent processes.  This means that if you modify something in one process the other process won't see the modification.

However, `multiprocessing` also provides [primitives that live in shared memory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) and can be accessed and modified by child processes. There are a [few different ways](https://github.com/sturlamolden/sharedmem-numpy) of [adapting numpy arrays](http://thousandfold.net/cz/2014/05/01/sharing-numpy-arrays-between-processes-using-multiprocessing-and-ctypes/) to use a shared memory `multiprocessing.Array`.  However, I'd recommend avoiding those at first (read up on [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) if you're not familiar with it).  There are cases where it's very useful, but it's typically to conserve memory, not to improve performance.

Therefore, it's best to do all modifications to a large array in a single process (this is also a very useful pattern for general IO).  It doesn't have to be the "main" process, but it's easiest to think about that way.

As an example, let's say we wanted to have our `parallel_rolling_mean` function take an output array to store things in.  A useful pattern is something similar to the following.  Notice the use of iterators and modifying the output only in the main process:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def parallel_rolling_mean(data, window, output):
    def windows(data, window):
        padded = np.pad(data, window, mode='edge')
        for i in xrange(len(data)):
            yield padded[i:i + 2*window + 1]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.imap(np.mean, windows(data, window))
    for i, result in enumerate(results):
        output[i] = result
    pool.close()

foo = np.random.rand(20000000).cumsum()
output = np.zeros_like(foo)
parallel_rolling_mean(foo, 10, output)
print output
```

Hopefully that example helps clarify things a bit.

---

### `chunksize` and performance

One quick note on performance: If we scale this up, it will get very slow very quickly. If you look at a system monitor (e.g. `top`/`htop`), you may notice that your cores are sitting idle most of the time.

By default, the master process pickles each input for each process and passes it in immediately and then waits until they're finished to pickle the next input.  In many cases, this means that the master process works, then sits idle while the worker processes are busy, then the worker processes sit idle while the master process is pickling the next input.

The key is to increase the `chunksize` parameter.  This will cause `pool.imap` to "pre-pickle" the specified number of inputs for each process. Basically, the master thread can stay busy pickling inputs and the worker processes can stay busy processing.  The downside is that you're using more memory.  If each input uses up a large amount of RAM, this can be a bad idea.  If it doesn't, though, this can *dramatically* speed things up.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def parallel_rolling_mean(data, window, output):
    def windows(data, window):
        padded = np.pad(data, window, mode='edge')
        for i in xrange(len(data)):
            yield padded[i:i + 2*window + 1]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.imap(np.mean, windows(data, window), chunksize=1000)
    for i, result in enumerate(results):
        output[i] = result
    pool.close()

foo = np.random.rand(2000000).cumsum()
output = np.zeros_like(foo)
parallel_rolling_mean(foo, 10, output)
print output
```

With `chunksize=1000`, it takes 21 seconds to process a 2-million element array:

```
python ~/parallel_rolling_mean.py  83.53s user 1.12s system 401% cpu 21.087 total
```

But with `chunksize=1` (the default) it takes about eight times as long (2 minutes, 41 seconds).

```
python ~/parallel_rolling_mean.py  358.26s user 53.40s system 246% cpu 2:47.09 total
```

In fact, with the default chunksize, it's actually far worse than a single-process implementation of the same thing, which takes only 45 seconds:

```
python ~/sequential_rolling_mean.py  45.11s user 0.06s system 99% cpu 45.187 total
```

Comment: Wow, extremely illuminating answer, Joe. I've read it several times and keep learning new things from it. Many, many thanks for taking the time to write such a thoughtful answer.